# GTM: Purpose of "Click Listener" Tag Type?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

Apologies if this is newbish. What is the point of the native "Click Listener" tag type in Google Tag Manager?

If you don't attach a trigger to Google Analytics (or some other service which creates logs), how can you even track that a tag has been fired? As my example, it seems that this GTM "Click Listener" tag type can only be acknowledged in the GTM preview / debug mode. Quite a limited usage. Or, does GTM have logging capabilities that I'm not aware of?

Obviously I'm missing something. ..

[image]

I've searched around and haven't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My best guess would be that this is for backwards compatibility. The first version of GTM did not have click trigger types, you needed to create your clicks via extra tags ("auto event tags", you find a [description e.g. at Simo Ahavas website](https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/auto-event-tracking-google-tag-manager/)).

Was your container perhaps created before 2014 in GTM v1 and then updated? Because in my accounts (all created as v2 containers) I do not even have those tags any more.

Comment: Thanks. I'll take a look. It seems I'll just be using the GA tags instead, anyway.